# php MySql login system in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have the following problem and was hoping that you could help me. I am busy building a website with a login system in Dreamweaver cs5. My login is created and I set up my testing server as the domain I am creating the website for.

This testing server does connect successfully. After this I am trying to establish a MySql connection. I insert my connection name which is dbConfig as well as the information of the MySql database that I set up on cpanel for this domain. I then get the following error:

HTTP Error code 404 file not found.

I don't know where to go from here as I have never worked with php or MySql before and am unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: Has nothing to do with `php` or `mysql`, the file either does not exist on the server or you're doing something with the `.htaccess` file that is not letting you get to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is parent domain then you need to upload your files to "WWW" folder from FTP. There might be a case where you may not see "WWW" folder. Some hosting cpanel have different default folder to upload files. For Example: Godaddy hosting cpanel has "html" folder where you can upload your files. But almost all other hosting has "WWW" folder.   If you are uploaded to subfolder For Example: www/test then to access your files you need to check like "http://example.com/test/" . OR if it in root folder then you just need to go to your domain url "http://example.com"